# Is there a way to specify a relative border-box width and a minimum content width?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to apply different box-sizing to different width specs? Can the min width be specified to use content-box and a % width to use border-box, or does box-sizing apply to all width specs on the element?

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1px;
}

input {
  /* including padding and border */
  width: 100%;
  /* based on content only */
  min-width: 2em;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
  /* emphasized border to really show the issue. */
  border: 8px solid;
}

div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>Content that increases the width of the column</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>...
        <!-- content less than the desired minimum width of the input element -->
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="42" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="42" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this particular case, the input should fill the width of the column without going beyond. Uncommenting the box-sizing fixes this, but makes the content space of the input less than the desired minimum width.

Comment: box-sizing applies to all width specs on the element.

Comment: Javascript solution it is then.

Comment: can you share a full code an a clear use case? maybe you are looking for the wrong solution and there is a better one without the need of box-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the JavaScript solution I've developed so far:

```js
$("[style*='min-width']").each(function(ndx, elem) {
    $elem = $(elem);
    $elem.css("min-width", parseInt($elem.css("min-width").slice(0, -2)) + $(elem).outerWidth() - $(elem).width() + "px");
})
```

```css
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 1px;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  /* including padding and border */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* emphasized border to really show the issue. */
  border: 8px solid;
}

div {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div>Content that increases the width of the column</div>
    </th>
    <th>
      <div>...
        <!-- content less than the desired minimum width of the input element -->
      </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="42" style="min-width: 2em;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="42" style="min-width: 2em;" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```